# How to rename a table in Symfony 3/Doctrine?

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I want to change a table from `order` to `shop_order`. First I alter the table name in phpmyadmin.

Furthermore I would have guessed, that changing the annotations would be sufficient:

```
/**
 * Order
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="shop_order")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Order { ...
```

But when running

```
php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql
```

It tries to create the table again:

```
CREATE TABLE `order` (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL ...
```

Is there any other file I need to change?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Clear the cache and try to alter the table name back with phpMyAdmin again. Once it is `order` again then use the doctrine command:

```
php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql
```

If you want Doctrine to execute the changes then add `--force` as well.

Also check your Doctrine configuration, it could be that is caching the metadata somewhere else (e.g. Memcache). You might need to clear that as well.

Doctrine caches on three levels: query cache, metadata cache and result cache. You may want to take a look at the metadata one.

```
doctrine:
    orm:
        auto_mapping: true
        # each caching driver type defines its own config options
        metadata_cache_driver: apc
        result_cache_driver:
            type: memcache
            host: localhost
            port: 11211
            instance_class: Memcache
        # the 'service' type requires to define the 'id' option too
        query_cache_driver:
            type: service
            id: my_doctrine_common_cache_service
```

So, if for example yours is set to Memcache then you'll have to reset Memcache as well.

Take a look at the docs [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/doctrine.html#caching-drivers).

Comment: sry, doesn't work either. Changed the name manually back, cleared cache and and ran `php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql`, which shows 0 changes :(

Comment: running on XAMPP on Windows, default config of symfony, so no changes in config.yml file, nothing hints at changed caching.

Comment: So now you have the table in the DB that is called `shop_order`, then the annotation like `@ORM\Table(name="shop_order")` and still when running `doctrine:schema:update` it tries to create an `order` table?

Comment: I assume you tried to manually drop the cache folder yourself, right? Also if you look at the Doctrine documentation it says that there's a `orm:clear-cache:metadata` command to force it as well. If none of those help try to change the annotation to `shop_order_2`. Does it want to create a `shop_order_2` along with `order` or just `order`?

Comment: Commands overview here: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/tools.html#command-overview

Comment: tried `php bin/console doctrine:cache:clear-metadata` (which is the symfony equiv. to `orm:clear-cache:metadata` i guess). Changing to `shop_order_2` has no effect, it just tries to create `order`

Comment: To me it sounds like the files running in the server are not being changed at all. If you create a brand new entity and Doctrine doesn't want to create the new table there you got another hint. You sure there is no sync between the files you're changing with your IDE and what is in your server? Have you tried restarting Apache and/or the entire server?

Comment: yes, restarted. There is sync because it's a local dev environment. Files are being changed, double checked it with two editors.

Comment: Oh dear lord ... I still got a `/src/Resources/config/doctrine/xml` folder in my project. And doctrine seams to prefer xml files to annotations in this case. Deleted the folder and everything works as expected ... Thank you all! Great answers!

Answer (score 4):

try to use `force`, like this:

```
php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force --dump-sql
```

And delete the cache please

---

If It doesn't work I advise you to use migration because seems tha doctrine doesn't recognize the change of the table name:

- Generate a new migration.
- Erase contents of `up(`) and `down()` methods and replace them with custom SQL (ALTER TABLE ... RENAME TO ...).

[Migration docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineMigrationsBundle/index.html)

Comment: Guess you got me bit wrong. It creates the table with the OLD table name again. Changed `@ORM\Table(name="order")` to `@ORM\Table(name="shop_order")`, run `php bin/console cache:clear` and then `php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force --dump-sql` creates the table `order` again but not the `shop_table`

Comment: Update answer with a new solution: migration

Comment: even this doesn't work for me. It migrates successfully `++ 1 migrations executed` and changes the table name as expected. But doctrine:schema:update still tries to create the old table and ignores the new one.

Comment: If It try to recreate the old table means that you can have a problem of cache if you have configured the doctrine cache for metadata for example

Comment: running on XAMPP on Windows, default config of symfony, so no changes in config.yml file, did not change caching behavior at all

Comment: so the doctrine cache isn't configured right? @Petermeir

Comment: ok first of all try to delete manually the directory var/cache, after try to make the migration / schema update @Petermeir

Comment: it is quite unbelievable to me. So I did emptied the cache folder completely, ran `php bin/console doctrine:migrations:generate`, changed the UP-code to include the `ALTER TABLE` command, ran `php bin/console doctrine:migrations:migrate 20170901131933
`, checked the annotation and ran `php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql --force` - still tries to create the table `order` :(

Answer (score 0):

Just change the name with DB administration tool, change the name in the entity accordingly, clear cache and you are good to go - `doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql` will then export no change.

Comment: nope, tries to create the old table again, see above answers